# How to use Snakemake container for htslib (bgzip + tabix)

Tags: docker, snakemake, singularity-container

I have a pipeline which uses a global singularity image and rule-based conda wrappers.

However, some of the tools don't have wrappers (*i.e.* `htslib`'s `bgzip` and `tabix`).

Now I need to learn how to [run jobs in containers](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#running-jobs-in-containers).

In the official documentation link it says:

> "Allowed image urls entail everything supported by singularity (*e.g.*, `shub://` and `docker://`)."

Now I've tried the following image from singularity hub but I get an error:

## minimal reproducible example:

### `config.yaml`

```
# Files
REF_GENOME: "c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS265.genomic.fa"
GENOME_ANNOTATION: "c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS265.annotations.gff3"
```

### `Snakefile`

```
# Directories------------------------------------------------------------------
configfile: "config.yaml"

# Setting the names of all directories
dir_list = ["REF_DIR", "LOG_DIR", "BENCHMARK_DIR", "QC_DIR", "TRIM_DIR", "ALIGN_DIR", "MARKDUP_DIR", "CALLING_DIR", "ANNOT_DIR"]
dir_names = ["refs", "logs", "benchmarks", "qc", "trimming", "alignment", "mark_duplicates", "variant_calling", "annotation"]
dirs_dict = dict(zip(dir_list, dir_names))

GENOME_INDEX=config["REF_GENOME"]+".fai"
VEP_ANNOT=config["GENOME_ANNOTATION"]+".gz"
VEP_ANNOT_INDEX=config["GENOME_ANNOTATION"]+".gz.tbi"

# Singularity with conda wrappers

singularity: "docker://continuumio/miniconda3:4.5.11"

# Rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------

rule all:
    input:
    expand('{REF_DIR}/{GENOME_ANNOTATION}{ext}', REF_DIR=dirs_dict["REF_DIR"], GENOME_ANNOTATION=config["GENOME_ANNOTATION"], ext=['', '.gz', '.gz.tbi']),
        expand('{REF_DIR}/{REF_GENOME}{ext}', REF_DIR=dirs_dict["REF_DIR"], REF_GENOME=config["REF_GENOME"], ext=['','.fai']),

rule download_references:
    params:
    ref_genome=config["REF_GENOME"],
        genome_annotation=config["GENOME_ANNOTATION"],
        ref_dir=dirs_dict["REF_DIR"]
    output:
    os.path.join(dirs_dict["REF_DIR"],config["REF_GENOME"]),
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["REF_DIR"],config["GENOME_ANNOTATION"]),
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["REF_DIR"],VEP_ANNOT),
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["REF_DIR"],VEP_ANNOT_INDEX)
    resources:
    mem=80000,
        time=45
    log:
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],"references","download.log")
    singularity:
        "shub://biocontainers/tabix"
    shell: """
    cd {params.ref_dir}
        wget ftp://ftp.wormbase.org/pub/wormbase/releases/WS265/species/c_elegans/PRJNA13758/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS265.genomic.fa.gz
        bgzip -d {params.ref_genome}.gz
        wget ftp://ftp.wormbase.org/pub/wormbase/releases/WS265/species/c_elegans/PRJNA13758/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS265.annotations.gff3.gz
        bgzip -d {params.genome_annotation}.gz
        grep -v "#" {params.genome_annotation} | sort -k1,1 -k4,4n -k5,5n -t$'\t' | bgzip -c > {params.genome_annotation}.gz
        tabix -p gff {params.genome_annotation}.gz
        """


rule index_reference:
    input:
    os.path.join(dirs_dict["REF_DIR"],config["REF_GENOME"])
    output:
    os.path.join(dirs_dict["REF_DIR"],GENOME_INDEX)
    resources:
    mem=2000,
        time=30,
    log:
        os.path.join(dirs_dict["LOG_DIR"],"references", "faidx_index.log")
    wrapper:
    "0.64.0/bio/samtools/faidx"
```

### Error

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Pulling singularity image shub://biocontainers/tabix.
WorkflowError:
Failed to pull singularity image from shub://biocontainers/tabix:
ESC[31mFATAL:  ESC[0m While pulling shub image: failed to get manifest for: shub://biocontainers/tabix: the requested manifest was not found in singularity hub

  File "/home/moldach/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/singularity.py", line 88, in pull
~
```

It appears this is a problem with the container?

```
(snakemake) [moldach@arc CONTAINER_TROUBLESHOOT]$ singularity pull shub://biocontainers/tabix
FATAL:   While pulling shub image: failed to get manifest for: shub://biocontainers/tabix: the requested manifest was not found in singularity hub
```

In fact, I experience this problem with other `biocontainers` containers.

For example, I also need to use a container to do `bowtie2` indexing and this is the error I get from the `biocontainers/bowtie2` versus another developers container of the same tool `comics/bowtie2`:

```
^C(snakemake) [moldach@arc CONTAINER_TROUBLESHOOT]$ singularity pull docker://biocontainers/bowtie2
FATAL:   While making image from oci registry: failed to get checksum for docker://biocontainers/bowtie2: Error reading manifest latest in docker.io/biocontainers/bowtie2: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
(snakemake) [moldach@arc CONTAINER_TROUBLESHOOT]$ singularity pull docker://comics/bowtie2
INFO:    Converting OCI blobs to SIF format
INFO:    Starting build...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob a02a4930cb5d done
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biocontainers does not allow `latest` as tag for their containers, and therefore you will need to specify the tag to be used.

From their [doc](https://biocontainers-edu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#get-the-docker-container):

> The BioContainers community had decided to remove the latest tag. Then, the following command docker pull biocontainers/crux will fail. Read more about this decision in Getting started with Docker

When no tag is specified, it defaults to `latest` tag, which of course is not allowed here. See [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/biocontainers/bowtie2/tags) for bowtie2's tags. Usage like this will work:

```sh
singularity pull docker://biocontainers/bowtie2:v2.4.1_cv1
```

Comment: I suppose using a specific tag, as opposed to the `latest` tag, also adds an additional layer of reproducibility; thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using another container solves the issue; however, the fact I'm getting errors from `biocontainers` is troubling given that these are both very common and used as examples in the literature so I will award the top-answer to whomever can solve that specific issue.

As it were, the use of `stackleader/bgzip-utility` solve the issue of actually running this rule in a container.

```
container:
    "docker://stackleader/bgzip-utility"
```

Once again, for those coming to this post, it's probably best to test any container first before running `snakemake`, *e.g.*  `singularity pull docker://stackleader/bgzip-utility`.